# Concat , Join knockout observableArry

Tags: javascript, join, knockout.js, concatenation

I have the following knockout Array

```
self.Countries= [{Name: "England"},{Name: "Italy"},{Name: "USA"}]
```

I want to get data like this

```
{"England" , "Italy" , "USA" }
```

Comment: you can't. The output you want is not a valid JS object

Comment: `self.Countries.map(a => a.Name)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the undocumented `utils` namespace.

http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html

[Signatures](https://gist.github.com/hyle/8840a083bcd1325a59ca)

```
ko.utils.arrayMap(self.Countries, function(item) {
    return item.Name;
});
```

Assuming, of course, you meant

```
["England" , "Italy" , "USA"]
```